# Removing a site collection feature

Tags: site-collection, feature

I am trying to remove a SharePoint feature that was deployed on a site collection level. Even after disabling it and removing the solution, it's still there. I deleted the folder from the TEMPLATES folder, but I prefer properly removing it.

I tried using Management Shell but the commands "`cannot find a Feature object with Path or Id...`", even if I copy and paste the folder name, the name in the xml file, etc.

Why is this so difficult to get rid of? Or should I not worry about it?

Comment: You retracted and deleted the solution in central admin?

Comment: That is correct. The solution is no longer in the store. Only the site collection feature remains.

Answer (score 1):

Proper way to remove the feature is

- Restract from the Site collections /Sites. i,e powershell [Disable-SPFeature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607879(v=office.15).aspx)
- Uninstall it i.e powershell U[Uninstall-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607873(v=office.15).aspx)
- Remove it. i.e powershell [Remove-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607748(v=office.15).aspx)

Now as it become orphan, you can remove either way

- use this [SharePoint Feature Administration and Clean Up Tool](http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/) to
  identify and remove them
- You can use the powershell to get this done.
  http://get-spscripts.com/2011/08/diagnose-missingwebpart-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found it! Turns out the solution was still in the gallery (despite the fact that I uninstalled and removed it). So I had to manually deactivate and delete it to remove the feature.